# Spring controller called twice while playing video with vlc-plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I play a video using the vlc-plugin and a Spring controller, the controller is called twice and the second time I get the error:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: null
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:438) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:426) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:457) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1793) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at fr.ina.archibald.controller.SubjectController.play(SubjectController.java:181) ~[archibald-controller-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at fr.ina.archibald.controller.SubjectController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a81fd8ce.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640) [spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at fr.ina.archibald.controller.SubjectController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$57b73e1f.play(<generated>) [spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409) [catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:84) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:517) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:408) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.50]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

Here is my client side embed element using vlc-plugin:

```
<div id="videoPlayerContainer">
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" src="subject/play?subjectId=X" width="500" height="300" />
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
/**
 * Gets stream to the broadcasting video of the subject.
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = PLAY)
public void play(final UserEntity sessionUser, @RequestParam("subjectId") int subjectId, HttpServletResponse res) {
    String path = null;
    try {
        SubjectEntity subject = subjectService.getById(subjectId);
        path = storageService.getFilePathBySubject(subject, FileType.SD);
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(path)) {
            logger.warn("Missing path of the '" + FileType.SD + "' file corresponding with the subject '" + subjectId + "': " + path);
            res.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            return;
        }
        File file = new File(path);
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName().replace(" ", "_"));
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
        res.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = res.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        res.flushBuffer();
        res.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        // return new FileSystemResource(path);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

On the second call, the exception is thrown on the line:

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

This is the only controller which is called twice.

I'm using Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE.

The video can be played anyway, but I'm not reassured by this situation...

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use firebug to check for server requests , you may get any idea.

Comment: Yes I already do it. I forgot to tell it, but there is only one request sent by the client.